# Get tarball of any public SVN repository

Tags: website, download, svn, zip

Is there a website that allows one to get the tarball of any specified SVN repository?

For example I want to get the tarball or zip of http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/ without having to use a local SVN client, but only use my browser or some command line HTTP client (such as `wget`).

This is mainly for some old unix machines that do not have SVN client.

Comment: AFAIK , there is no online svn browser.

Answer (score 1):

This should be possible since I can see a [PHP SVN Client implementation](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/4270.html),

> This class can be used to retrieve files from an SVN repository in pure PHP,
>   thus without using separate programs.
>
> It accesses a given remove SVN repository using the WebDAV protocol and perform several types of operations:
>
> - List all files in a given SVN repository directory
> - Retrieve a given revision of a file
> - Retrieve the log of changes made in a repository or in a given file between two revisions
> - Get the repository latest revision

If you cannot get someone hosting such a client,
you could consider setting up a local machine that will do this for your other older machines.

---

Also look at **Stackoverflow: [An online SVN client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192310/an-online-svn-client)**.
<sup>and, uh, how old *are* these unix machines? can't you get a regular svn client built for them?</sup>

Comment: As far as I know, those PHP Clients are making heavy use of the exec() comment using a local SVN Client. I'm not sure if this would work with remote repositories.

Answer (score -1):

I can see the need of retrieving tarballs of svn repositories without having access to an svn client. But I don't see why would you need to get those to old computers.

You probably won't do development there, since that would require an svn client anyway, so you could commit your changes back.

You probably don't need to get the repo tarballs onto those computers for building stuff from those sources, because you don't need whole svn repos for that, just snapshots of certain revisions.

Since you talk about browser usage, I have to assume that those old unix computers are networked. So you could just retrieve the svn repos using another computer, create tarballs and serve them yourself from there over HTTP.

Also, if you have scripting languages installed on the old computers, perhaps you shall look for a svn client written in those languages. There are svn bindings for [Perl](http://search.cpan.org/~mschwern/Alien-SVN-1.4.6.0/src/subversion/subversion/bindings/swig/perl/native/Client.pm) and [Python](http://pysvn.tigris.org/) at least.

Finally, you can use those bindings to write your own trivial svn client that would do the checkout.